# How to use the \substitutefont in the normal font?

Tags: fonts, packages

How to use the `\substitutefont` in the normal font?

I need substitute `cmr (\familydefault)` to `yvo` (Venturis ADF Old)
but is no work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{substitutefont}

% Normal
\substitutefont{T1}{cmr}{yvo} % Venturis ADF Old

% Sans Serif
\substitutefont{T1}{cmss}{pzc} % Zapf Chancery

% Monospaced
\substitutefont{T1}{cmtt}{phv} % Helvetica

\begin{document}

\textbf{Normal}

\lipsum[1]

\textbf{Sans}

\textsf{\lipsum[1]}

\textbf{TT}

\texttt{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that you have some questions that have received answers but you haven't accepted any of them. Please consider revisiting those questions and accepting the answer that best solved your problem. I know that you've accepted answers to most of your questions; this is just a reminder for the other ones ;-) (Please forgive me if I bother you with this.)

Comment: ok, is that it took me a while to test, has no problem remembering, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically can't for the standard size. The default font should be specified by changing `\rmfamily`:

```
\renewcommand{\rmfamily}{yvo}
```

In the case of Venturis ADF it's better to say

```
\usepackage[<options>]{venturis}
```

(see the package documentation for the `<options>`).